# Extract the latent space learned from a Neural Network

Tags: plotting, neural-networks, sound, cluster-analysis

I would like to visualize and cluster vectors learned in the latent space of a Neural Network.

I am trying to cluster audio tokens, but I don't know what they represent. So the task is to automatically label all tokens that are similar.

I am trying to explore Mathematica, instead of python, and learning from this tutorial:
https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/machine-learning-for-audio/extract-features-using-a-neural-net.html?product=mathematica

Consider this:

```
(* generate random audio token for sake of example *)
audioProps = 
  RandomChoice[{"Sin", "Triangle", "Sawtooth", "Square", "Pulse", 
    "Impulse"}, 1000];
audioFreqs = Table[RandomInteger[{220, 880}], 1000];
audio = AudioGenerator /@ Transpose[{audioProps, audioFreqs}];
```

now, from the tutorial:

```
net = NetModel["Wolfram AudioIdentify V1 Trained on AudioSet Data", 
  "Size" -> "Small"]
mainNet = NetExtract[net, {1, "Net"}]
featureExtractor = 
 NetChain[{NetMapOperator[NetDrop[mainNet, -3]], 
   AggregationLayer[Max, 1], FlattenLayer[]}, 
  "Input" -> net[["Input"]]]
```

At this point I do:

```
fsp = FeatureSpacePlot[# & /@ audio, FeatureExtractor -> featureExtractor]
```

But what I want to do is to extract the latent space, and have more control.
Example, I would like to cluster the coordinates shown on `FeatureSpacePlot`, or even better cluster the vectors from the last layer learned by `featureExtractor`.

I tried:

`NetExtract["featureExtractor", 3] // last layer`

and

`NetExtract["fsp", Last]` // latent space ??

Both give an error.

Comment: Your NetExtract commands are wrong because you've got quotes `"..."` which you don't need. Also `//` is not a comment in Mathematica and will be interpreted as `Postfix`. These `(* ... *)` and these `(** ... **)` are for comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DimensionReduce` like this:

```
drvecs = 
  DimensionReduce[audio, 2, FeatureExtractor -> featureExtractor, 
   Method -> "UMAP"];
clusters = FindClusters[drvecs];
ListPlot[clusters, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @flinty, sorry for having oversught your answer